# why create the SHA-1 fingerprint before using google service sign in by keytool?

Tags: android

i want to use google service sign in, first, i should to create the SHA-1 fingerprint, but i don't know my app how to relate with the SHA-1 fingerprint. what is their relationship? thanks.

Comment: yes their is, authorization on Android uses a SHA1 fingerprint and package name to identify your app instead of a client ID and client secret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#get-an-api-key

Go to the above mentioned URL and get a key for your project. Just follow the instructions and put the key in your manifest file.